# Sessions destroys in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, codeigniter-3

I have a `PHP`site written with `CodeIgnitor 3`. I store sessions in database table. The problem is sessions' destroys after about 30-40 minutes of it's life during day time, and after about 60-80 minutes at night. The oldest sessions just removes from table while other still live.
My **config**:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = '<cookie_name>';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = '<table_name>';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 30000;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Earlier I was using `Codeigniter 2` and problem was the same.

Comment: so what are u trying to ask? prevent the session destroy?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want sessions live at least 8 hours.

Comment: show your code how you set your session

Comment: Session sets automatically by `CodeIgnitor`, I'm just using `session->set_userdata()` and `session->userdata()`.

Comment: `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;` increase this value in seconds you want to alive your sesson

Comment: I want unlimited session, so, I set `$config['sess_expiration']` to `0`.

Comment: @DmitriyKorobkov You couldn't get unlimited session last. `0` means your session will last until browser close.

Comment: @RejoanulAlam, only if browser clears it's cookie before close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by myself. There is **a mistake in official documentation**. If I set `$config['sess_expiration']` to `0`, `CodeIgniter` gets `sess_expiration` parameter from *php.ini* file (suddenly!). So, setting `$config['sess_expiration'] = $config['sess_time_to_update']` solves my problem.

---

`CodeIgniter` overrides `garbage collector` which runs with 1% chance during request to site, so thats why sessions were live longer at night.
Thanks to everybody participating in discussion.